# How to assign values from one array to another for n times

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I am trying to create a schedule of who uses a specific item on which day.

I have 2 arrays.
**one with dates** &
**another with names and how many days they can use the item.**

i have managed to create dates array using this.

```
function dateArray($from, $to, $value = NULL) {
    $begin = new DateTime($from);
    $end = new DateTime($to);
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $days = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    $baseArray = array();
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $dateKey = $day->format("d-m-Y");
        $baseArray[$dateKey] = $value;
    }

    return $baseArray;
}

$dates_array = dateArray('01-01-2014', '30-09-2014',true);

print_r($dates_array );
```

which gives me dates as

```
Array
(
    [01-01-2014] => 1
    [02-01-2014] => 1
    [03-01-2014] => 1
    [04-01-2014] => 1
    [05-01-2014] => 1
    [06-01-2014] => 1
    [07-01-2014] => 1
    [08-01-2014] => 1
    [09-01-2014] => 1
and so on.
)
```

i have another array of names having **name as key** and **days as value** , they can use the item like this.

```
$names_array = array("name1" => "4", "name2" => "3", "name3" => "1");
```

Now i would like to assign names to dates depending on how many days the person can use the item. 
like this.
**I need my final output array to be like this**

```
Array
(
    [01-01-2014] => name1
    [02-01-2014] => name1
    [03-01-2014] => name1
    [04-01-2014] => name1
    [05-01-2014] => name2
    [06-01-2014] => name2
    [07-01-2014] => name2
    [08-01-2014] => name3
    [09-01-2014] => name1
and so on. notice name1 comes again 
)
```

so i am trying to get output like above but i am failing at the while loop inside the foreach.
so far i have tried this.

```
function dateArray($from, $to, $value = NULL) {
    $begin = new DateTime($from);
    $end = new DateTime($to);
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $days = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    $baseArray = array();
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $dateKey = $day->format("d-m-Y");
        $baseArray[$dateKey] = $value;
    }

    return $baseArray;
}

$dates_array = dateArray('01-01-2014', '30-09-2014',true);

$names_array = array("name1" => "4", "name2" => "3", "name3" => "1");

print_r($dates_array );

$new_dates = array();

foreach($dates_array as $dates => $key){
//echo $dates;
    foreach ($names_array as $name => $days){

        while($days <= 1){
        $new_dates[$dates] = $name ;
        $days = $days - 1;
        }
    }
}

print_r($new_dates);
```

But my final array is empty.

so how can i solve this ?

Comment: Not that this was part of your question....but wont that overwrite certain values?  Because what happens if two users both have $days<=1 on the same day.  You'll just overwrite the $new_dates[$dates] value.

Comment: the idea is , names should be set as values while dates as key. if days = 1 then it should asign only names one and then move on to next name.

Comment: Sorry I still dont understand what youre trying to achieve.  Im running this ins PHP sandbox and it only every seems to assign the last value of the foreach.  Because obviously it will overwrite.  Like what decides that name1 repeated on that example you show

Comment: Because if the day is always <=1 then you will always without fail, end up with name3 as a value for every date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator) whereby the second array (names) loops around when needed:

```
$names_array = array();

// unwind the array values
foreach (array("name1" => "4", "name2" => "3", "name3" => "1") as $value => $freq) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $freq; ++$i) {
        $names_array[] = $value;
    }
}

// attach both arrays
$m = new MultipleIterator;
$m->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator(array_keys($dates_array)));
$m->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($names_array)));

// build final array
$result = array();
foreach ($m as $value) {
    $result[$value[0]] = $value[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably go like this...

```
while($days <= 1){
    $new_dates[$dates] = $name ;
    $names_array[$name] = $days - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this one

```
$dates_array = array_keys(dateArray('01-01-2014', '30-09-2014',true));
$names_array = array("name1" => "4", "name2" => "3", "name3" => "1");
$new_dates = array();

$daysindex = 0;
while($daysindex < count($dates_array)){
    foreach ($names_array as $name => $day){
        for($x = 0; $x<$day; $x++){
            if(isset($dates_array[$daysindex])){
            $new_dates[$dates_array[$daysindex]] = $name ;
        $daysindex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($new_dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = dateArray('01-01-2014', '30-09-2014',true);  
$names = array('name1' => 4,'name2' => 3,'name3' => 1);

$count = current($names);
$name = key($names);

foreach($dates as &$value) {   
    $value = $name;

    //if we've displayed a name $count times, move to the next name
    if(--$count == 0) {
        //if we're at the end of $names, wrap around
        if(false === next($names)) {
            reset($names);
        }

        $count = current($names);
        $name = key($names);        
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```